# Update user meta data with Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress, metadata, contact-form-7

I have successfully gotten my Contact Form 7 form to create new users, which adds details to custom metadata fields perfectly, however I am now wanting to create an Edit Profile form and want to be able update the user meta.

How could I tweak this exact code to update user meta instead of create a new user?

```
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'create_user_from_registration', 1);

function create_investor_from_registration($cfdata) {
    if (!isset($cfdata->posted_data) && class_exists('WPCF7_Submission')) {
        // Contact Form 7 version 3.9 removed $cfdata->posted_data and now
        // we have to retrieve it from an API
        $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
        if ($submission) {
            $formdata = $submission->get_posted_data();
        }
    } elseif (isset($cfdata->posted_data)) {
        // For pre-3.9 versions of Contact Form 7
        $formdata = $cfdata->posted_data;
    } else {
        // We can't retrieve the form data
        return $cfdata;
    }
    // Check this is the user registration form
    if ( $cfdata->title() == 'Investor Registration') {
        $password = $formdata['password'];
        $email = $formdata['your-email'];
          $industry = isset($formdata['industryinterest'][0])?$formdata['industryinterest'][0]:'';
           $stage = isset($formdata['menu-608'][0])?$formdata['menu-608'][0]:'';
            $country = $formdata['country'];
             $singlepooled = isset($formdata['radio-263'][0])?$formdata['radio-263'][0]:'';
              $leadinvestor = isset($formdata['radio-264'][0])?$formdata['radio-264'][0]:'';
               $amount = $formdata['amount-invest'];
                $portfolio = $formdata['portfolio-examples'];
                 $about = $formdata['about-investor'];
        $name = $formdata['firstname'];
        $lastname = $formdata['lastname'];
        // Construct a username from the user's name
        $username = $formdata['your-email'];
        if ( !email_exists( $email ) ) {
            // Find an unused username
            $username_tocheck = $username;
            $i = 1;
            while ( username_exists( $username_tocheck ) ) {
                $username_tocheck = $username . $i++;
            }

            $username = $username_tocheck;
            // Create the user
            $userdata = array(
                'user_login' => $email,
                'user_pass' => $password,
                'user_email' => $email,
                'nickname' => reset($username),
                'display_name' => $name,
                'first_name' => $name,
                'last_name' => $lastname,
                'industryinterest' => $industry,
                'stageinterest' => $stage,
                'countryinterest' => $country,
                'singlepooled' => $singlepooled,
                'leadinvestor' => $leadinvestor,
                'investamount' => $amount,
                'portfolio' => $portfolio,
                'about' => $about,
                'role' => 'customer'
            );



            $user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata );
            if ( !is_wp_error($user_id) ) {
                // Email login details to user
                $blogname = wp_specialchars_decode(get_option('blogname'), ENT_QUOTES);
                $message = "Welcome! Your login details are as follows:" . "\r\n";
                $message .= sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $username) . "\r\n";
                $message .= sprintf(__('Password: %s'), $password) . "\r\n";
                $message .= "NEW LOGIN URL HERE";
                wp_mail($email, sprintf(__('[%s] Your username and password'), $blogname), $message);
            }

wp_set_current_user( $user_id );
wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id, false, is_ssl() );

        }
    }
    return $cfdata;
}

add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'create_investor_from_registration', 1);
```

Below is a snippet I tried to change myself, but it doesnt seem to work and i'm not sure why... I shorteed it down to just the 'about' field to test one single field for ease.

```
function update_investor_profile($cfdata) {
    if (!isset($cfdata->posted_data) && class_exists('WPCF7_Submission')) {
        // Contact Form 7 version 3.9 removed $cfdata->posted_data and now
        // we have to retrieve it from an API
        $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
        if ($submission) {
            $formdata = $submission->get_posted_data();
        }
    } elseif (isset($cfdata->posted_data)) {
        // For pre-3.9 versions of Contact Form 7
        $formdata = $cfdata->posted_data;
    } else {
        // We can't retrieve the form data
        return $cfdata;
    }
    // Check this is the user registration form
    if ( $cfdata->title() == 'Update Profile') {


         if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

                 $about = $formdata['about-investor'];



                // Getting the WP_User object
                $user = wp_get_current_user();


     $userdata = array(
                     'about' => $about
            );


           if( isset($about) ){
    update_post_meta($current_user, 'about', $about);
} 


            }



    }
    return $cfdata;
}

add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'update_investor_profile', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an easy task.  Contact form 7 plugin gives no access to the construction of form fields, and therefore the only way to pre-fill a field on form load is through javascript.  There is a plugin extension that does this, [Post My CF7 Form](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-my-contact-form-7/), but is not designed to handle User profiles per-say.  It has a built-in mechanism to allow you to programmatically handle the submission and loading of a form and its values using hooks, but again not an easy answer to provide.  I will give you here the outline of the steps you need to take to achieve this,

using the above plugin, you would need to hook the filters,

**'cf7_2_post_save-post'** to map your form to your profile.
You will need to use the mapping function on a dummy post, use the post-type 'post' for this, so as to trigger the hook,

```
add_action('cf7_2_post_save-post', 'save_your_profile', 10, 3);
function save_your_profile($sky_key, $submitted_data, $submitted_files){
  //check this is your form, using the unique key.
  if('profile-form'!= $cf7_key) return;
  //load your profile values 
  $submitted_data['field-name'];
}
```

**'cf7_2_post_form_values'** to prefill the fields on form load

```
add_filter('cf7_2_post_form_values', 'load_profile_values', 10, 4);
function load_profile_values($values, $form_id, $post_type, $cf7_key){
  //check this is your form, using the unique key.
  if('profile-form'!= $cf7_key) return $values;
  //load your profile values 
  $values['field-name']=<field_value>;
  return $values;
}
```

**alternative custom solution**

Since you already have a working solution to create/save new profile, you could create a custom javascript to fill the fields of your form when the page has loaded.  Use the 'do_shortcode_tag' hook to detect when your form is being loaded,

```
add_filter('do_shortcode_tag', 'append_script_to_form',10,3);
function append_script_to_form($output, $tag, $attr){
  if('contact-form-7' != $tag){
    return $output;
  }
  if(!isset($attr['id']) || 2 != $attr['id']){ //check for your form.
    return $output;
  }
  //check if the user is logged in and has a profile, else return $output.
  //load the profile.
  $script = '<script>'.PHP_EOL;
  $script .= '(function($)( $(document).ready(function(){'.PHP_EOL;
  //each field is wrapped in a span.field-name element.
  $script .= '$("span.wpcf7-form-control-wrap.field-name input").val("'.$profile_values["field-name"].'");'.PHP_EOL;
  //... and so on
  $script .= '});})(jQuery)'.PHP_EOL;
  $script .= '</script>'.PHP_EOL;
  //finally tag your script at the end of the form output.
  return $output . $script;
}
```